# How do stackoverflow and others do the requests not reflected in the network tab?

Tags: ajax, http, websocket, request, protocols

Maybe this is a naive question (and surely a repeated question from someone else), but I don't seem to find the result anywhere. Usually when you have continuous `ajax` requests or any request, the request will appear in the network tab of the debugger (tab of the image below).

**network window**

[image]

However, when I see the `stackoverflow`, `mathoverflow` or any other `overflow` we see the questions with new activity tab like so:

[image]

The count increments when new questions appear, however, nothing is reflected in the Network tab, which for me is really weird. Shouldn't you have to make repeating calls in order to get this information? Where is this happening? Sorry if the question is somehow naive.

Comment: Who are `they`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They establish a long-lived connection from the browser to the server. Over this connection, the server “pushes” events to the browser, causing page updates.

There are several ways to do this.

Stack Overflow uses the [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) protocol:

[image: Stack Overflow using WebSocket to receive pushes from the server]

Another approach is [Server-Sent Events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events), which relies on the HTTP protocol’s streaming features.

In any case, once established, the long-lived connection soon disappears from view in the Network pane, obscured by newer short-lived requests/connections.

Comment: I see. I was wondering for some days how was it possible, but I think I just never crossed that term before. Thanks!